# searching multiple values in string array in javascript/react

Tags: javascript

I have many values in string array. ['A','B','C','D','E'].

I have to search like this. if Array contains `A ,B` then it is `admin`. if it contains `C,E` then it is `resercher`. if it is containing `B,C,D` then it is `manager`.

I am writing below code for it. its not working. can you please help me on same.

```
 const groups = ['A','B','C','D','E']


for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    if (groups[i]==='A'&&  groups[i] ==='B'  ) setAdmin(true);
    if (groups[i]==='C' && groups[i] ==='E'   ) setResearcher(true);
    if (groups[i]==='B' && groups[i] ==='C' && groups[i] ==='D' ) setRiskMgr(true);

}
```

I know it is not working because it is comparing element with multiple values. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to utilize your logic

```js
const groups = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

const userGroups = {
  admin: ['A', 'B'],
  researcher: ['C', 'E'],
  riskManager: ['B', 'C', 'D']
}

function setAdmin() {
  console.log('admin')
}

function setResearcher() {
  console.log('researcher')
}

function setRiskMgr() {
  console.log('risk manager')
}


if (userGroups.admin.every(group => groups.includes(group))) setAdmin(true);
if (userGroups.researcher.every(group => groups.includes(group))) setResearcher(true);
if (userGroups.riskManager.every(group => groups.includes(group))) setRiskMgr(true);
```

Less repeated code with a separate object for role checks

```js
const groups = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

const userGroups = {
  admin: {
    values: ['A', 'B'],
    set: function() {
      setAdmin(true)
    }
  },
  researcher: {
    values: ['C', 'E'],
    set: function() {
      setResearcher(true)
    }
  },
  riskManager: {
    values: ['B', 'C', 'D'],
    set: function() {
       setRiskMgr(true);
    }
  }
}

function setAdmin() {
  console.log('admin')
}

function setResearcher() {
  console.log('researcher')
}

function setRiskMgr() {
  console.log('risk manager')
}

for(const key in userGroups) {
  if(userGroups[key].values.every(group => groups.includes(group))) {
    userGroups[key].set();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ChrisG mentioned, you can use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead.

```js
const groups = ['A','B','C','D','E']

if (groups.some(group => ['A', 'B'].includes(group))) {
  setAdmin(true);
} else if (...) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite a simple solution with `Array.includes`

```
 const groups = ['A','B','C','D','E']

 if(groups.includes('A') && groups.includes('B')) {
    setAdmin(true);
 } else if(groups.includes('C') && groups.includes('E')) {
   setReasercher(true)
 } // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no issue with React `useState`, are you referring to OR, `||` statement, if so @Nick Vu has the answer, since you are just looping through the `groups` list, there is NO WAY to have two same element at single integration.

Else, if you want to achieve AND, `&&` condition, then solution is otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
const groups = ['A','B','C','D','E']

function setAdmin() {
    console.log('admin')
}


function setResearcher() {
  console.log('researcher')
}

function setRiskMgr() {
  console.log('risk manager')
}



if(arr.some(a=>a==="A")&&arr.some(a=>a==="B")) setAdmin(true);



if(arr.some(a=>a==="C")&&arr.some(a=>a==="E")) setResearcher(true);



if(arr.some(a=>a==="B")&&arr.some(a=>a==="C")&&arr.some(a=>a==="D")) setRiskMgr(true);
```